# Why does nib loading pick up my categories?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have extended NSScrollView to be non-flipped with a category (by default it is flipped). Then I added an NSScrollView to my application with Interface Builder. The NSScrollView is flipped.

How can this happen? I don't include my category in any source file in my project. I only compile it in which seems to somehow be enough. And I did do a clean build, just to be safe.

And most importantly: How can I change this behavior? I don't want my nibs to automatically pick up all categories they can find, on the other hand it could be handy to sometimes include them. But I've always seen categories as opt-in, not opt-out as this seems to be here.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Categories apply to the entire class; all instances of NSScrollView ANYWHERE in your program will pick up the new behavior. For this reason, it's generally not a good idea to override existing methods in a category; you're changing the behavior of that method for **all** users of the class, not just your own instances.

So categories are neither opt-in nor opt-out; they are absolute and overriding. If the category is compiled into the program, then *every* instance that class will be affected. They can neither opt in nor opt out; the new behavior is forcibly imposed upon them by the runtime. Keep that in mind when using categories.

If you want to change the behavior for *some* instances, then you should make a subclass of NSScrollView (call it UnflippedScrollView or something) and override the method there. Then use your subclass where you need an unflipped scroll view.

Comment: Just to emphasize something from the question: “I don't include my category in any source file in my project. I only compile it in which seems to somehow be enough.” That is exactly correct. If the category exists at all in your program, for which the only requirement is that it be built by the target, then it affects the class throughout your program, including all instances everywhere—including in nibs.

Comment: To drive this point even further: Never override an existing method with a category. Some Apple framework methods are themselves implemented in categories. If two categories implement the same method, the behavior is undefined. Overriding should be done in subclasses, not categories. Categories are for adding new methods, not overriding existing ones.

Comment: A followup to Peter's point: categories apply to all instances of a class from the point that the category is loaded (they effectively apply retroactively to existing instances). This matters in cases where you implement a category in a dynamic library and load it manually. When you load the library, the class is modified. The point is that in principle categories can modify classes at any point in time (not just at application startup), making category overrides even more nondeterministic.

Comment: Oh, ok, i must have completely misunderstood categories then. When I start thinking about it even makes more sense that way.